# Do I need to configure my remote server when using shell_exec();

Tags: php, linux, remote-server, shell-exec

I am trying to encrypt a string using a command created in C in my remote server where my database is located.  But shell_exec keeps giving me a call to undefined function error.
What are the steps to make this function defined? 
Am I using this function correct?

```
function encrypt($string) {
    $output = shell_exec('');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
}

$string = "some_string"; 
$encryptedString = encrypt($string);
```

Comment: Are you sure shell_exec is allowed by the hoster? If PHP runs in safe mode it's disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to blacklist the `shell_exec` from the [`safe mode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php).

**Sidenote** : If it works, you need to escape the `$string` using the [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) before passing it to your `shell_exec()` function.

Like this..

```
function encryptTFS($string) {
    $output = shell_exec('tea32 -e -"'.escapeshellarg($string).'" -ofilenameoutout');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
}

$string = "some_string"; 
$encryptedString = encryptTFS($string);
```

Comment: I do not think PHP is running in safe mode, how would I find the blacklist of functions

Comment: Open your php.ini and search for `disable_functions =` keyword and remove the `shell_exec` from there.

Comment: the keyword `shell_exec` does not follow `disable_functions =` in my php.ini file